# codenameone - How to add two icons to android homscreen during app installation?

Tags: android, codenameone

How to add multiple icons for different activities to android homescreen during app installation or app first init on codenameone?

Comment: Add the LAUNCHER category to the intent-filter for the Activity in your AndroidManifest

Comment: This is really a native Android question, you can use native interfaces http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html and build arguments http://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_sending_arguments_to_the_build_server to adapt the native Android answer to Codename One

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly just do something like this:

Add an `Activity` subclass under the `native/android` hierarchy. Then in the [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) settings properties defined the activities manifest entry under `android.xapplication` e.g.:

```
android.xapplication=<activity android:name="MyActivity"><intent-filter><category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter>
```

Notice that its all in a single line, that is on purpose since the UI doesn't allow line breaks there but its still valid XML.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but finally i change my design app and no longer use multiple icon launcher.